# Structuring mysql chat query display order

Tags: mysql

I have a small chat app that I am working on, but got stuck with ordering and limiting the results that are displayed from the DB. I want to limit the results by 20 and display the latest results at the bottom of the HTML container DIV, I would need to get the highest ID of the chat table - 20 and then display those results. This is my current query

```
SELECT chat_box.*,

(SELECT MAX(chat_id) AS last FROM chat_box) AS last
FROM chat_box 
ORDER BY chat_id ASC
LIMIT last,20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `MAX` if you just want to display the last 20 entries of the table.

```
SELECT `you`, `should`, `use`, `a`, `column`, `list`
FROM chat_box
ORDER BY chat_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

**Update**

```
SELECT `you`, `should`, `use`, `a`, `column`, `list`
FROM chat_box
WHERE chat_id > (SELECT MAX(chat_id) - 20 FROM chat_box)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but of course this is the first thing I tried, will list out the columg names as suggested

Comment: Great now this works, appreciate your help. Man becoming a query master is in the working. I had the right idea just needed to polish my implementation. Thanks again.

Comment: @kabuto178 Keep at it. Takes a lot of practice, time and patience.

Comment: I will, doing work with JOINS daily, and many to many table linking

Comment: If I wanted to save the inner select query answer to a value, and be able to access this value how would I do that?

Comment: You would need to use a variable. Some [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: I was thinking of using the value of the second SELECT query, could I use AS value?

Comment: @kabuto178 I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT chat_box.*, MAX(chat_id) AS last FROM chat_box 

ORDER BY chat_id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

or if you want see the correct in your query u should do like that

```
   SELECT chat_box.*,

 (SELECT MAX(chat_id) AS last FROM chat_box LIMIT last,20) AS last2
    FROM chat_box 
 ORDER BY chat_id ASC
```

Comment: You should be using a `GROUP BY` here.